# Regression Line in Mathematica using FIT function

Tags: webmathematica, mathematica-online

I dont know if I am confused or if I am doing  this incorrectly.

I have two data sets

```
 a={1,2,3,4,5}
 b={6,7,8,9,10}
```

Mathematica will translate the sets as

```
 a = {1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}
 b = {1,6},{2,7},{3,8},{4,9},{5,10}
```

I want to do a scatter plot and find the regression line. I know how to do a scatter plot but I am not sure how to do a regression line for both data sets.

I looked around and it was suggested to me that I can use this

```
 regline = Fit[Join{a,b},{1,x},x]

 Show[ListPlot[{a,b}], Plot[{regline}, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

This works but the "Join" makes the data sets A and B like this

```
 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

and translates to this.

```
{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8},{9,9},{10,10}.
```

Wouldn't the regression line need to be figure out on the data sets

```
 {1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}
 {1,6},{2,7},{3,8},{4,9},{5,10}
```

and not

```
 {1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{6,6},{7,7},{8,8},{9,9},{10,10}.
```

The regression line would be different for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
b = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
data = Join[Transpose[{Range[Length[a]], a}], Transpose[{Range[Length[b]], b}]]
regline = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[{regline}, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 
>     9}, {5, 10}}
>
> {2.5 + 1. x}

[image]

Comment: I see why you did   data = Join[Transpose[{a, a}], Transpose[{a, b}]] but how  would you did it if data points were a={11,23,55,33,55} and b = {4,66,56,56,55} @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: @user2896245 Better now? I use `Range` to produce `{1,2,3,4,5}`...

Comment: Yes, Thank you! You are the best!

Comment: @user2896245 You're welcome!